# Printing an Array's components but it prints null + the value at the specified index (JAVA)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner amount = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many names would you like to enter?: ");
        int total = amount.nextInt();
        String[] mainArray = new String[total];
        for (int i=0; i<total; i++){
        Scanner names = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Gimme a name!: ");
        String name = names.nextLine();
          mainArray[i]=mainArray[i]+name.charAt(0);
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainArray)+"");
    }
}
```

Input: 3
Input: Moe
Input: Curly
Input: Vader

Returns

```
How many names would you like to enter?: 3
Gimme a name!: Moe 
Gimme a name!: Curly
Gimme a name!: Vader
[nullM, nullC, nullV]
```

The code should return "MCV", no spaces. I have no clue why it's printing Null beforehand when it prints the specified character right after, it should print after the Array is filled, or at least I thought it should.

Comment: `mainArray[i]=mainArray[i]+name.charAt(0);` What value do you think is stored in `mainArray[i]` at this point?

Comment: or maybe a better question is what is in mainArray[i] when you start?

Comment: A small tip: you don't have to create new scanners for reading different input. You can use amount to read in the names. You should also close your scanners after reading them with "amount.close() and names.close()"

Comment: I thought it would store the first character of the Scanner input. Ex input Moe, mainArray[0] would be M

Comment: `mainArray[i]=name.charAt(0);`

Comment: `mainArray[i]=mainArray[i]+name.charAt(0);` is the same as `mainArray[i]=null+name.charAt(0);` in your code. Do you really think that this is what you want to do?

Comment: A good rule of thumb for programming is to first try to explain everything to the computer in English (or your native language), so you get the logic ironed out.  Then you can translate that into computer code.  There's nothing wrong with the code you've written, it just doesn't do what you want it to because you got the logic wrong.  Flow charts can also be really helpful.

Comment: Do not close any Scaner that uses System.in before the end of the program. Once you close such a scanner, it will close System.in, and good luck reopening that.

Comment: Yep @NomadMaker, sorry. You should close a scanner after reading it *unless* its System.in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable of type `StringBuilder` or `String` or `StringBuffer` etc. to append the desired values to. Currently, you are appending the values to the array elements which have been initialized as `null`. Moreover, you do not need multiple instances of `Scanner` (**and never in a loop**).

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many names would you like to enter?: ");
        int total = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
        String[] mainArray = new String[total];
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            System.out.print("Gimme a name!: ");
            mainArray[i] = scanner.nextLine();
            if (mainArray[i].length() >= 1) {
                sb.append(mainArray[i].charAt(0));
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(mainArray));
        System.out.println(sb);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
How many names would you like to enter?: 3
Gimme a name!: Moe
Gimme a name!: Vader
Gimme a name!: Curly
[Moe, Vader, Curly]
MVC
```

Note that I have used `Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine())` instead of `scanner.nextInt()` so that the new line character entered after the integer input is not left to be consumed by the next scan. Check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo) to learn more about it.